# Case statement for HIVE platform

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table with the following columns:

> - ID
> - Scheduled Date
> - Status
> - Target Date

I need to extract 'Status' corresponding to minimum 'Appointment Date' for each ID. If not available then I need to extract status corresponding to the minimum 'Target Date' for that ID. 
Sample data:

```
ID  | Scheduled_Date    | Status |  Target_Date
1      12/11/2017        Completed  12/11/2017
1      12/12/2017        Completed  12/12/2017
2      12/13/2017        Completed  12/13/2017
3      12/14/2017        Pending    12/14/2017
3      12/15/2017        Pending    12/15/2017
4                        Confirmed  12/18/2017
4                        Confirmed  12/19/2017
5      12/14/2017        Completed  12/14/2017
5      12/15/2017        Pending    12/15/2017
```

Can you please correct the code that I am trying to write?

```
SELECT ID, 
    CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL THEN 
        CASE WHEN MIN(SCHEDULED_DATE) IS NOT NULL 
        THEN STATUS 
        ELSE
        END         
        CASE WHEN MIN(TARGET_DATE) IS NOT NULL 
        THEN STATUS
        ELSE ''
        END
FROM FIRST_STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT id,
       status
FROM yourtable t
WHERE COALESCE (Scheduled_Date,
                Target_Date) IN
    (SELECT MIN(COALESCE (Scheduled_Date,Target_Date))
     FROM yourtable i
     WHERE i.ID = t.id
     GROUP BY i.ID);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dfd00/3)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` analytic function:

```
select id,
       status
from
(
select id,
       status,
       row_number() over(partition by id, order by nvl(Scheduled_Date,Target_Date)) rn
  from yourtable t
)s 
where rn=1
;
```